# CPC Ad optimization algorithms to improve campaign performance

Tags: algorithm

I am searching for algorithms (and codes) which usually ad networks use to improve their campaigns results (higher Click through rate). is there a place you know that i can find it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! As for your question, it's too broad for Stack Overflow -- in fact, there are books, websites, and an entire sector of the tech industry dedicated to this topic. A Google search for "click-through rate optimization" or similar terms is probably the best place to start.

Comment: Thanks, I did search a lot about this and posting here was my last shot, which helped.